# Google bar chart: what to do with too close values

Tags: google-visualization

Does anybody please have an advise on what to do with the too close values in different series, which overlap - like in the right bar below?

[My chart URL - please click to see the parameters](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=700x280&cht=bvo&chco=3399FF,CCCCFF&chd=t:1552,1885,3451,2745|3927,6133,8053,2790&chxl=0:|2010-44|2010-45|2010-46|2010-47&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,006633,12,0,_,000000&chxr=1,0,8053&chds=0,8053&chbh=140,10,0&chm=N**$,,0,,12|N**$,,1,,12)

[image]

I can't find a good [chm parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#gcharts_data_point_labels) for all of the data I have.

Shouldn't overlapping be handled by the Google charts automatically in this case? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in Google's API. But unfortunately, it is a deprecated API...